# Converting time formats in zsh

Tags: time, converters, zsh

I have created a z shell script that takes a time option argument. (ex: --time 00:03:30). I would like the user to be able to enter the time in a format other than HH:MM:SS. My script can already convert HH:MM:SS into seconds (which is what the end result needs to be), but the HH:MM:SS format is clunky. So, I made a function that will convert another format (#h#m#s) into the original one:

```
    if [ "$(echo "$1" | grep -E "([[:digit:]]+[hms]|[[:digit:]]+[hms][[:digit:]]+[hms]|[[:digit:]]+[hms][[:digit:]]+[hms][[:digit:]]+[hms])")" ]; then
        if [ "$(echo "$1" | grep "h")" ]; then
            H="$(echo "$1" | sed -E 's|.*([[:digit:]]+)h.*|\1|')"
        else
            H=00
        fi
        if [ "$(echo "$1" | grep "m")" ]; then
            M="$(echo "$1" | sed -E 's|.*([[:digit:]]+)m.*|\1|')"
        else
            M=00
        fi  
        if [ "$(echo "$1" | grep "s")" ]; then
            S="$(echo "$1" | sed -E 's|.*([[:digit:]]+)s.*|\1|')"
            else
            S=00
        fi
        echo "$H:$M:$S" | sed -Ee 's|:([[:digit:]]):|:0\1:|' -e 's|^([[:digit:]]):|0\1:|' -e 's|:([[:digit:]])$|:0\1|'
    fi
```

Yes, I have created my own solution. I came here to find a better one. Also, if you know of any other formats that you can convert into to seconds please let me know.

Comment: aaaaand my solution doesn't even work. hahaha

Comment: Post your not working solution, maybe the error is easy to find

Comment: The code in the original question is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
% zmodload zsh/datetime
% echo $(( $(strftime -r '%H:%M:%S' 01:01:12) - $(strftime -r '%H:%M:%S' 0:0:0) ))
3672
```

Comment: I will look further into that, but your solution returned 0 when I tried it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @thefilthypineapple I tried zsh 4.3.10 and also got 0. Maybe you need zsh 5.0.0 to get the right result in this way.

Comment: Yeah - "zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)". However, I want to share my script. Is there a more generic way of doing this?